# Gson crashes app when receiving empty String instead of object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I trying to populate a response object that looks like this using Gson:

```
public class RegisterUserResponse extends BaseResponse {

  @SerializedName("tokens")
  private Tokens tokens;

  public RegisterUserResponse() { }

  public Tokens getTokens() {
      return tokens;
  }
}
```

My Gson builder looks like this:

```
RegisterUserResponse response = getGson().fromJson(jsonResponse, RegisterUserResponse.class);
```

When I receive a JSON that contains the object everything's fine.
**The problem begins when "tokens" return empty**, like in this JSON:

```
{"tokens":""}
```

and I get this exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line # column #
```

Which I do understand, but don't know how to avoid.

Comment: json basics ... if "tokens" property "is a Tokens class" then `null` should be used `{"tokens":null}`... and error is self explanatory: *Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING*

Comment: @Selvin Since i'm not controling the server, I can't control the response.
I wish I could get null.
Don't see a reason to downgrade. I'm trying to deal with a situation.

Comment: then you have to use custom deserializer